# Terminal won't open

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, chromebook

I have 16.04 that I put on my chromebook using Crouton. When I click on the terminal, it pops up on the dash and acts like it's loading, but then quickly disappears and does nothing. When I try to enter "gnome-terminal" into xterm, I get the error:

```
Error constructin proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: 
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited. 
Process org.gnome. 
Terminal exited with status 8
```

Comment: Same happens here with an Xsession (not a regular lightdm session).

I note that if I launch the terminal with "dbus-launch gnome-terminal" it will work fine (in this case it will start a separate dbus process and the gnome-terminal will comunicate directly with it).

Also found this page: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ
which suggests this is a problem related to locale.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigations I found a workaround, following the hints provided here: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231152/gnome-terminal-stopped-working/243696#243696

First you need to export the DISPLAY (the one on which X is running), LANG and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variables.

To get the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, you can pick it from the environment of one of the gnome-session process, or even from the dbus-daemon process:

```
$ ps aux | grep dbus-daemon
xuser   10752  0.0  0.0  42764  2532 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
xuser   10804  0.0  0.0  43620  4012 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-UhfCCoqTSP
xuser   10891  0.0  0.0  42896  3932 ?        S    13:50   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
```

In this case the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-UhfCCoqTSP".

Now you can do something as below (from an xterm or from a console shell)

```
  export DISPLAY=:1
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-UhfCCoqTSP
  dbus-update-activation-environment --verbose LANG DISPLAY DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Alternatively you can also set all the variables with

```
 dbus-update-activation-environment --all
```

but I discovered only those three ones are required.